# Compiled css failed with nested mixin with ampersand

Tags: css, sass, ampersand, scss-mixins

I am trying to nest mixin together to update style. But I found that the output css seems not what I expected.

I am wondering if there is any way can nest mixin together and having ampersand on the right.

Below are some sample code and expected result.

Thanks.

HTML:

```html
<html class="classA">

  <div class="itemA">
    <div class="itemB">Item B</div>
  </div>

</html>
```

SCSS:

```
@mixin add-style-when-classA-exist() {
  .classA & {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin add-style-when-classB-notExist() {
  html:not(.classB) & {
    @content;
  }
}

.itemB {
  color: blue;

  @include add-style-when-classB-notExist() {
      color: green;
  }

  @include add-style-when-classA-exist() {
    color: red;

    @include add-style-when-classB-notExist() {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

Actual CSS Output:

```css
.itemB {
  color: blue;
}
html:not(.classB) .itemB {
  color: green;
}
.classA .itemB {
  color: red;
}
html:not(.classB) .classA .itemB {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Expected CSS Output:

```css
.itemB {
  color: blue;
}
html:not(.classB) .itemB {
  color: green;
}
.classA .itemB {
  color: red;
}
html:not(.classB).classA .itemB {
  color: yellow;
}
```